# Set object to null for matching criteria in Set via mutate in ES6/TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have `Set`s of objects that are nested like this:

```
const mySet: Set<any> = new Set([
 {
   id: 1,
   text: "hello",
   success: true,
   sub: {
     id: 5,
     text: 'hi',
     success: true,
     sub: {
       id: 7,
       text: 'hi ...',
       success: true,
       sub: {
         id: 12,
         text: 'hi :)',
         success: false,
       }
     }
   },

 {
   id: 2,
   text: "hey",
   success: true,
   sub: null,
 }
])
```

As you can see `id:1` has a `sub` that has also has its own `sub` and it goes on like this. This may be between 0 to X as many as. What I want to do is, find success `false` and change the object to `null` and keep the array.

I tried this. This mutates:

```
mySet.forEach(s => {
  s.text = "Override text"
})
// OR... This works for first element but what about recursively?
mySet.forEach(s => {
  if(s.sub.success === false) s.sub = null
})
```

This way I can override values. `forEach` mutates original object. But how do I do that for multiple subs? I have no idea on this.

Basically, I want to iterate if `sub` exists and recursively iterate, if found, set it to `null` if success is `false`.

Expected Result:

```
[
 {
   id: 1,
   text: "hello",
   success: true,
   sub: {
     id: 5,
     text: 'hi',
     success: true,
     sub: {
       id: 7,
       text: 'hi ...',
       success: true,
       sub: null
     }
   },

 {
   id: 2,
   text: "hey",
   success: true,
   sub: null,
 }
]
```

Any suggestion?

This is what I have tried so far. I placed this in `forEach` But this replaces all objects not the last element found.

```
do {
    if (sub.success === false) {
      m.sub = null
    } else {
      m.sub = m.sub.sub
    }
}
while (m.sub !== null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create function which takes an object as an argument. If `success` is false, set `sub = null`. Else if the object has a non-null `sub` property, recursively call the function on the `obj.sub` object. Call this function for every item in the array or set using `forEach`

```js
const input = new Set([{id:1,text:"hello",success:true,sub:{id:5,text:"hi",success:true,sub:{id:7,text:"hi ...",success:false,sub:{id:12,text:"hi :)",success:false,}}},},{id:2,text:"hey",success:true,sub:null,}]);

function checkSub(obj) {
  if (!obj.success)
    obj.sub = null
  else if (obj.sub)
    checkSub(obj.sub)
}

input.forEach(checkSub)

console.log([...input]) 
// Set won't be displayed in the snippet console
// so, converting it to an array for demo
```

Answer (score 0):

In `m.sub = m.sub.sub`, you are using `m.sub` as the "iteration variable". Use a local variable instead.

```
var obj = …;
while (obj.sub) {
    if (!obj.sub.success) {
        obj.sub = null;
    } else {
        obj = obj.sub;
    }
}
```

You can also write that as

```
for (var obj = …; obj.sub; obj = obj.sub) {
    if (!obj.sub.success) {
        obj.sub = null;
        break;
    }
}
```